Why do float decimals reappear even after they are truncated and cast as String?
I need to store a float with n decimals in a variable but it seems too complicated.
If I run this code:
float testFloat = -18.479999542236328f;
System.out.println(getFloatAsStringIWithNDecimals(testFloat, 9));
System.out.println(testFloat + "");
System.out.println(getFloatAsStringIWithNDecimals(testFloat, 3));
System.out.println(getFloatWithNDecimals(testFloat, 3));
System.out.println(Float.parseFloat(getFloatAsStringIWithNDecimals(testFloat, 3)));
System.out.println(getFloatAsStringIWithNDecimals(Float.parseFloat(getFloatAsStringIWithNDecimals(testFloat, 3)), 9));
System.out.println(getFloatWithNDecimals(Float.parseFloat(getFloatAsStringIWithNDecimals(testFloat, 3)), 3));
System.out.println(getFloatAsStringIWithNDecimals(getFloatWithNDecimals(Float.parseFloat(getFloatAsStringIWithNDecimals(testFloat, 3)), 2), 9));

public static String getFloatAsStringIWithNDecimals(float f, int nDecimals) {
    return String.format(Locale.US, "%.0"+nDecimals+"f", f);
}

public static float getFloatWithNDecimals(float f, int nDecimals) {
    int multiplier = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= nDecimals; i++) {
        multiplier *= 10;
    }

    return ( (int)(f * multiplier) ) *1f / multiplier;
}

public static float getFloatWithNDecimals(float f) {
    return getFloatWithNDecimals(f, 2);
}

this is the output:
-18.479999542
-18.48
-18.480
-18.48
-18.48
-18.479999542
-18.48
-18.479999542

Why do these output, even if I truncate the decimals, cast them to int and then divide them by 100 and even if I truncate them by converting the float to String using String.format?
Thanks

Are you familiar of representation errors in floating point mathematics? Try searching for that. Use BigDecimal if you need it.

I knew about the problem with floating poitn precision, as in other programming languages, but why the decimal reappears with Float.parseFloat(getFloatAsStringIWithNDecimals? If it parse the float from a string that contains a float with only 3 decimals, why does it put the other decimals at the end of the float? It seems that it uses internally the same initial float value for both the testFloat var and the returned string value. (I'll search for "representation errors in floating point mathematics")

If you need to store a number with exactly N places past the decimal, you don't want to use float or double, because that's not what they do, they're binary, they don't have any "decimal digits".

The fundamental issue is that the decimal number 18.48 does not exist as a float, or as a double.  It just doesn't.  If you take the decimal representation 18.48 (perhaps as a string) and convert it to float or double, you don't have the number 18.48 any more.  If you take a float variable containing a number like 18.479999542236328, and try to round it to exactly 18.48 using something like your getFloatWithNDecimals function, it won't work, because the new float variable you try to compute it in can't represent 18.48, either.


I simply need to store a float with n decimals in a variable but it seems too complicated...

That's not what float can store. Your question is similar to: "I just want to store the word 'hello' in an int variable but it seems too complicated". Or "I want to put a golf club in my bowling ball bag and it does not fit".
floats store a number with fixed precision, but in binary.
Grab a piece of paper. Go write 1/20th on it. No problem. "0.05".
Now do the same thing and write 1/15th on it. 0.06666666666666... oh dear. You can't do it. No notepaper is big enough to exactly write it down.
The reason 1/20 does work and 1/15 does not is because you're writing it in base 10, and the prime divisors of 10 are 5 and 2. If the denominator of your fraction breaks down into solely prime factors 5 and 2, then it will 'work' (20 is 2*2*5 - that's all fives and twos, so that works), and if there's even one non-5, non-2 value in there then it will not; 15 is 5*3 - there' a 3 in there, so it won't work.
In binary, the only divisors are 2. So the denominator needs to break down into just any amount of 2s.
Here is another trivial example which you really should write and run so you fully understand the following concept: float and double are fundamentally imprecise and cannot be rounded as floats or doubles, ever, and if you try, you will fail.
double v = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) v+= .1;
System.out.println(v == 1.0);

Which will print false which is highly surpising. Since when is ten times oh point one not equal to one? But it isn't, because 10 as a denominator is 5*2 which includes a not-2, so whilst one tenth works fine in decimal notation (0.1), it does not in binary notation - it's like 0.3333333.....
The result of round(1/3 to 10 decimal places) * 3 is not 1.0 (it is 0.9999999999), the result of round(1/10 to 10 binarial places) * 10 is not 1.0 either.
Now try the same stunt, but replace 0.1 with 0.125 (which is one eighth, which does work: 8 breaks down to 2*2*2 - that's all twos, so is precise in float/double math), and indeed eight times an eighth really is equal to 1.0.
Now that you know that, you know that 'round to 8 places' is a nonsense operation on float/double. They simply cannot do it - because you meant "8 places in decimal notation".
So what DO I do?
You can use BigDecimal which really does work in decimal, but is hard to use and very slow, and difficult to divide with (asking BD to divide 1 by 3 throws an exception unless you tell it how to round for the same reason you will 'throw an exception' if I ask you to write down one third on a piece of paper - that is not possible without introducing some error).
The better option is to round when you render - whenever that number is turned into a string, round then. For example:
double v = 5;
v = v / 3.0;

System.out.printf("%.4f", v);

Will round your number to 1.6667 during the print operation which works great. You can use String.format if you don't want to emit this string directly to standard output. Any method that is specced to 'return a rounded numeric value' cannot have double or float as return type. It needs to have BigDecimal or String.
Alternatively, if you have a set fixed point you want to operate on for all of it, for example 'I want to store eurocents but never half of a cent, so always round to 2 decimal digits', then instead store the smallest unit in a long. So, don't store double priceOfThisThing = 1.23; for something that costs 1 euro and 23 eurocents. Instead store long priceInCents = 123;.
Sidenote: float is useless
double is faster, better, stronger. There is no reason to ever use float unless either [A] you are going to make an array of them that is very large (more than ~100k elements!), or [B] some spec explicitly requires IEEE32 float math. Which is extremely rare. or [C] the platform that ends up running this code is likely a 32-bit chip that does its floating point math in 32 bit as well. At time of writing (2024), these chips are extremely rare.
Yes, double is 'larger'. You'd think that implies they are 'slower'. Unless you have really exotic hardware, that'd be incorrect; chips simply work faster on that size they were designed to operate on. And for modern chips (anything built less than a decade ago) that's double, not float.
In other words, the odds that float is right are effectively zero.

If you are doing calculations with money use BigDecimal. It is designed for that kind of use case. It is premature optimization to use an integer type if there is no need.

I think you meant to write System.out.printf("%.4f", v);.  (The % is missing your code.)

@aled No, using BD is overengineering/YAGNI. BD is not designed for that kind of use case. If it was, it would have included some useful principles, such as 'divide this amount into this many accounts, assigning any remainder that doesnt fit the configured precision randomly'. JodaMoney would be an example of something 'designed for it'. It's either long, or jodamoney. BD is never the answer.

@VGR Thanks for noticing that one; answer edited. Feel free to edit to fix such code typos next time, your eye for detail is always appreciated!
